# If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and $X$ is absolutely continuous then $X+Y$ is absolutely continuous

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I'm stuck in the following problem.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ independent random variable where $X$ is absolutely continuous. Then $X+Y$ is absolutely continuous.

This is what I have so far.

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F}, P)$ the probability space where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables. Let $Z=(X,Y)$ a random vector and let $g$ the sum function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, that is, $(x,y) \longmapsto x+y$, clearly $g$ is Borel measurable since it's continuous. Then $g\circ Z =X+Y$ is a random variable.

Now since $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, the law of $Z$ is the product measure of the law of $X$ and the law $Y$, that is, $P_Z =(P_X \times \,P_Y)$, where $P_Z=PZ^{-1}$ and $(P_X \times \,P_Y)$ is the product measure. Then for $A$ in $\mathscr{B} (\mathbb{R})$ we have

\begin{align*}P_{X+Y}(A)=P_Z (g^{-1 }(A))&=(P_X \times\,P_Y)(g^{-1 }(A))\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} P_Y(g^{-1}(A)_x) dP_X \tag{definition of prod. measure}\end{align*}

Where $g^{-1}(A)_x= \{y\in \mathbb{R}:(x,y)\in g^{-1}(A)\}=\{y\in \mathbb{R}:x+y\in A\}$, that is, $g^{-1}(A)_x =A-x$. Now we know that $P_X<<\lambda$, since $P_X$ is finite, the Radon-Nikodym Thm (which we abbreviate as R-N), implies that there is a non-negative measurable funcion $f$, such that $P_X(B)= \int_B f d\lambda$ for any Borel set $B$. Then, by the chain rule for R-N we have

\begin{align*} \int_{\mathbb{R}} P_Y(g^{-1}(A)_x) dP_X &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} P_Y(A-x) f (x)\, \lambda(dx)
\end{align*}

and from here I'm stuck, I'd appreciate a hint to conclude. Thank you.

Edit: Thus,

\begin{align*} \int_{\mathbb{R}} P_Y(g^{-1}(A)_x) dP_X
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\chi _{A} (x+y) P_Y(dy) \right) \lambda(dx)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\chi _{A} (x+y) \lambda(dx)  \right) P_Y(dx) \tag{Fubini-Tonelli}\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y)\chi _{A} (x) \lambda(dx)  \right) P_Y(dx) \tag{$\lambda$ is invariant}\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y)\chi _{A} (x) P_Y(dy)  \right) \lambda(dx) \tag{Fubini-Tonelli}\\
&=\int_{A} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y) P_Y(dy)  \right) \lambda(dx) \end{align*}

Am I right?

Comment: $$P(X+Y\in A)=\iint \mathbf 1_{x+y\in A}f_X(x)dxdP_Y(y)\implies f_{X+Y}(z)=\int f_X(z-y)dP_Y(y)=E(f_X(z-Y))$$

Comment: If you want to write the product, use `\cdot` or `\times`.

Comment: @Did, I believe to arrive to your answer, I have two use the fact that $P_Y(A-x)= \int \chi_{A-x}(y) dPY=\int \chi_A (x+y) dPY$, the Fubini-Tonelli thm two times (since everything is non-negative is ok) and the fact that Lebesgue measure is invariant under translation.